# Selected Range to upper case Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to run this code but is giving me an error according to my point of view it should work but unable to understand what is the actual issue.

I hope someone can help.

**Error is**  `Compile error: Expected Function or Variable`

on this line `rng.Value = makeUpper(rng.Value)`

```
Sub Uppercasecells()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Selection
        rng.Value = makeUpper(rng.Value)
    Next rng
End Sub

Sub makeUpper(rng As Range)
    Dim v As Long, vUPRs As Variant
    With rng
        vUPRs = .Value2
        For v = LBound(vUPRs, 1) To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
            vUPRs(v, 1) = UCase(vUPRs(v, 1))
        Next v
        .Cells = vUPRs
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `vUPRs` is not an array when `rng` is a single cell.

Comment: `makeUpper` is a subroutine. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: `makeUpper` expects a `Range` but you're passing it `rng.Value`.

Comment: Yeah that is my mistake so in that way i cannot use the selected range then. what could be other way to have this worked for selected range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `makeUpper` is a subroutine and does not return anything, unlike a `Function`.
- `makeUpper` expects a `Range` but you're passing it `rng.Value`.
- `vUPRs` will not be an array if `rng` is a single cell.
- Note that you only loop through the first dimension (rows) of `vUPRs` (left that way if that's intended).

Rewritten:

```
Sub Uppercasecells()
    makeUpper Selection
End Sub

Sub makeUpper(rng As Range)
    Dim v As Long, vUPRs As Variant

    With rng
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' create array if rng is a single-cell
            ReDim vUPRs(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
            vUPRs(1, 1) = .Value2 
        Else
            vUPRs = .Value2
        End If

        For v = LBound(vUPRs, 1) To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
            vUPRs(v, 1) = UCase(vUPRs(v, 1))
        Next v

        .Value2 = vUPRs
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to loop through the second dimension of `vUPRs`, then:

```
Sub makeUpper(rng As Range)
    Dim v As Long, w As Long, vUPRs As Variant

    With rng
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            ' create array if rng is a single-cell
            ReDim vUPRs(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            vUPRs(1, 1) = .Value2
        Else
            vUPRs = .Value2
        End If

        For v = LBound(vUPRs, 1) To UBound(vUPRs, 1)
            For w = LBound(vUPRs, 2) To UBound(vUPRs, 2)
                vUPRs(v, w) = UCase(vUPRs(v, w))
            Next
        Next

        .Value2 = vUPRs
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is working very well @BigBen but i assumed 1 thing which is not working that is when i select mutiple columns it does not change the CASE but works for single column. How to make it work for all selection instead of selection in single column. Looking forward to your reponse.

Comment: Did you see the second part of the answer where I address this? Also for clarification, are you selecting multiple contiguous columns like A:F, or separated like A,D,F?

Comment: Yes i have used this part as well but when i select contiguous columns like `A:F` or like `G:M` it does not work..

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I've edited the answer with the entire code of `makeUpper`, which works for me.

Comment: I apologise its my bad i missed just one thing after `Next`  that is `.Value2 = vUPRs` sorry to bother you.

Comment: All good. This way if anyone else stumbles on this thread in the future, they'll have the exact code to use.